# Troubleshooting `require': cannot load such file -- stripe_mock (LoadError) After updating from rails 6.0 to 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Updated Gemfile to `rails 6.1`
`bundle update rails` and
`rails app:update` (accepted all and manually made some changes.

I did some other stuff but I can't remember exactly.

The error persists even if I check out a commit from before the update, so it appears I broke something beyond what's in the app.

Also created a separate, fresh rails app (6.1) and it worked fine.

Now I'm getting this on `rails s`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    48: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    47: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    46: from /path/to/app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    45: from /path/to/app/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    44: from /path/to/app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    43: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    42: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    41: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    40: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    39: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    38: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    37: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    36: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    35: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    34: from /path/to/app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    32: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    31: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:105:in `register'
    30: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    29: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    28: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    27: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    26: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    25: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    24: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    23: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    22: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    21: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    20: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    19: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    18: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    17: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    16: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    15: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    14: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:88:in `register'
    13: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    11: from /path/to/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    10: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
     9: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
     8: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
     7: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
     6: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
     5: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     4: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
     3: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:93:in `register'
     1: from /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- stripe_mock (LoadError)
```

If I remove stripe mock from Gemfile, it just throws same error on the next require.

`gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', '~> 2.5.6', :require => 'stripe_mock'`

After removing ^ it will throw same error for another file, and so one... So it's not an issue w/ any one gem.

`ms/bootsnap-1.9.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in require': cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)`

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up with `gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', '~> 3.1.0.rc2', require: 'stripe_mock'` to deal with a [different problem](https://github.com/stripe-ruby-mock/stripe-ruby-mock/issues/646), 3.1.0rc2 is working fine for me.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks. Found a workaround. I'd pushed to remote after updating rails, but before breaking it. Cloned fresh from remote and now it's working fine. Dunno what the actual issue was though.